# jquery 1.4.2 find/filter function does not work in IE

Tags: jquery

This below code works perfectly find in all the browsers except IE. The problem I'm seeing only in IE is the email is not getting pre-populated in the input field. I'm using jquery 1.4.2. My guess is some of the jquery 1.4.2 inbuilt function is not compatible with IE.

The same code works fine with jQuery 1.7. Unfortunately I'm constrained with using jQuery 1.4.2(because it is an enterprise wide decision to stick with jQuery 1.4.2 across all sites) so I cannot upgrade to latest jQuery and fix this.Any other solution that can be used?

```
tempLogin.filter('H4').html("ACCOUNT").end()
    .filter('p').html("There is already a " + siteVarObj(C.options.siteCode).siteName + " account associated with this email address.<p>Please enter your password to login.</p>")
    .end()
    .filter('.hsImages').html("");

pageHs.find('input#aim_Email').val(C.options.email).end()
    .find("input#aim_Password").focus();

finalTemplate = pageHs.find(".hsPlaceHolder").html(tempLogin);
C.options.currentPage = finalTemplate;
C.setPage('hsTemplate');
```

Comment: << Unfortunately I'm constrained with using jQuery 1.4.2 >>  Why?

Comment: You need to figure out where in the chains the method(s) fail. Is it `filter()`? Is it `find()`? Is it both?